# Updateprogress won't show

Tags: asp.net, download, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have 2 aspx pages with 1 button on each page.
When I click the button on the first page, it does some work and then redirects to the other page.
When I click the button on the second page it compresses files and downloads the zip file,
But it never shows the updateprogress in the updatepanel.
I Want to show some text and a gif, then I want to show a complete message and close the second page when click on the complete message.

This is first aspx page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Run_Button" runat="server" ImageAlign="Bottom" ImageUrl="~/download.png" OnClick="run_Click1" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('Run_Button').style.display = 'none';"  /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100"
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="But1Stuff" runat="server">
            <h1>Cleaning</h1>
            <img src="1LBN.gif" style="height: 227px; width: 241px" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This is the beginning of the click in code behind:

```
protected void run_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Run_Button.Visible = false;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    // the rest of code
}
```

This is the second aspx file:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Download_Button" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Download_Button" runat="server" 
            ImageAlign="Bottom" 
            ImageUrl="~/images.jpg" 
            OnClick="download_Click1" 
            OnClientClick="document.getElementById('Download_Button').style.Display = 'none';" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" 
    DisplayAfter="100"
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1>Compressing files and downloading</h1>
            <img src="1LBN.gif" width="64" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

And the beginning of the click on second code behind file:

```
protected void download_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Download_Button.Visible = false;
    // the rest of code
}
```

This is the download code:

```
string dirRoot = "E:\\WashingMachine\\";
string[] filesToZip = Directory.GetFiles(dirRoot, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string zipFileName = string.Format("cleaned-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.zip", DateTime.Now);

using (MemoryStream zipMS = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMS, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (string fileToZip in filesToZip)
        {
            if (new FileInfo(fileToZip).Extension == ".zip") continue;
            if (fileToZip.Contains("node_modules")) continue;
            byte[] fileToZipBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToZip);
            ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileToZip.Replace(dirRoot, "").Replace('\\', '/'));
            using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open())
            using (BinaryWriter zipFileBinary = new BinaryWriter(zipEntryStream))
            {
                zipFileBinary.Write(fileToZipBytes);
            }
        }
    }

    using (FileStream finalZipFileStream = new FileStream("E:\\WashingMachine\\" + zipFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        zipMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zipMS.CopyTo(finalZipFileStream);
    }
    string filePath = "E:\\WashingMachine\\" + zipFileName + " ";
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    string Outgoingfile = zipFileName;
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

I haven't got any of my tries for the complete message to work so that is not in here.
What is wrong for the updatepanel in the second aspx?
Please help so i can finish this :)
What have i done wrong?